# How do I get the value of the result body rather than full result body in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a flask api endpoint that when you query it, response with the following:

```
{
    "embeddings": [
        [
            0.09660455584526062,
            0.020427927374839783,
            -0.006049016956239939
        ]
    ]
}
```

I have some code in scala that queries it and extracts the response but it currently gets the whole body like this:

> {"embeddings": [[-0.09660455584526062, 0.020427927374839783, -0.006049016956239939]]}

I would just like to extract the body inside the "emdeddings" like:

```
    [
        [
            0.09660455584526062,
            0.020427927374839783,
            -0.006049016956239939
        ]
    ]
```

Question is how do I do this:

Code so far:

```
  def callFlaskApiEndPoint(url: String): String => String = (requestBody: String) => {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    val formatted_content = "text" -> requestBody
    val jsonData = compact(render(formatted_content))
    try {
      val result = Http(url)
        .postData(jsonData)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
        .option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(10000))
        .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(5000))
        .asString

      result.body
      //tried following but not working so commented out
      //(parse(result.body) \\ "embeddings").extract[String]
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        "{}"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pretty(render(parse(str) \\ "embeddings"))
```

This gives:

```
[ [ -0.09660455584526062, 0.020427927374839783, -0.006049016956239939 ] ]
```